# max date from different tables with same primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

3 tables: Item has 7k rows but Price and Data tables are individually approx 1gb in size with 10 million rows each.

```
Item- itemid,itemName
Price- itemid,itemPrice,itemDate(Date)
Data- itemid,itemPrice,itemDate(Date),Some other fields
```

How to get min(itemid) such that max(itemDate) from Price> max(itemDate) from Data for every itemid?

MyApproach (Working but very slow takes approx. 2 hrs for this query)

```
select min(itemid)
from Price p
where p.itemid in (select itemid from Item)
  and p.itemDate > (select max(itemDate) from Data d where d.itemid = p.itemid);
```

Comment: if you are talking about ')' in last part '= p.itemid);' then in mysql it works.

Comment: since you made the edit you must have know the answer @James Z

Comment: No idea how you think fixing your typos & removing Indian words would relate to MySQL experiance. I do know how this should be done in SQL Server but I don't know MySQL internals that well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to optimize your query, following is an example. You can use indexes for further optimization.

```
select min(itemid) from Price p join item i using(itemid) where  and p.itemDate > (select max(itemDate) from Data d join price using(itemid));
```

hope this helps

Comment: it didn't worked out(returned null).Still a question: how is itemid in inner query is corresponding to itemid in main query such that they both are same.